# Google Feed API

Tags: javascript, api, rss, google-feed-api

I'm having trouble getting Google's load feed to work. Example is supposed to be at www.eslangel.com

I put this code in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAO2BkRpn5CP_ch4HtkkOcrhQRKBUhIk5KoCHRT6uc9AuUs_-7BhRyoJdFuwAeeqxoUV6mD6bRDZLjSw">
</script>
```

And then, just to test, I copied and pasted their sample code using a Digg feed into the body of my blog, but there's no result of any kind.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
/*
*  How to load a feed via the Feeds API.
*/

google.load("feeds", "1");

// Our callback function, for when a feed is loaded.
function feedLoaded(result) {
  if (!result.error) {
    // Grab the container we will put the results into
    var container = document.getElementById("content");
    container.innerHTML = '';

    // Loop through the feeds, putting the titles onto the page.
    // Check out the result object for a list of properties returned in each entry.
    // http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#JSON
    for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
      var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}

function OnLoad() {
  // Create a feed instance that will grab Digg's feed.
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml");

  // Calling load sends the request off.  It requires a callback function.
  feed.load(feedLoaded);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, did you also create a container for the feed? :-)

Try placing

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

before the feed loading script.

Comment: I didn't initially put a container there, but there is now and it's still not working. see www.eslangel.com

Comment: Check last line, "google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);&#8203;", try to remove nasty symbols in the end.